# php memcache returning END when it shouldnt

Tags: php, memcached

I'm currently learning memcache. Doing some simple get/set queries and found out a strange behavior.

Thats how i am doing set and get queries.

```
$memClient = new MemcacheClient('localhost', 11211);
$memClient->set('get1', 'value of get1');
$memClient->set('get2', 'value of get2');
$memClient->get('get1');
$memClient->get('get2');
```

Thats my simple MemcacheClient

```
Class MemcacheClient
{
    private $socket;

    private $reply;

    private $replies = [
        'OK' => true,
        'EXISTS' => false,
        'DELETED' => true,
        'STORED' => true,
        'NOT_STORED' => false,
        'NOT_FOUND' => false,
        'ERROR' => null,
        'CLIENT_ERROR' => null, 
        'SERVER_ERROR' => null
    ];

    public function __construct($host, $port)
    {
        $this->socket = stream_socket_client("$host:$port", $errno, $errstr);

        if(!$this->socket) {
            throw new \Exception("$errst ($errno)");
        }
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        $reply = $this->query("get $key");

        return $reply;
    }

    public function set($key, $value, $exptime = 0, $flags = 0)
    {
        return $this->query(array("set $key $flags $exptime ".strlen($value), $value));
    }

    private function query($query)
    {
        $query = is_array($query) ? implode("\r\n", $query) : $query;
        fwrite($this->socket, $query."\r\n");

        return $this->parseLine();
    }

    private function parseLine()
    {
        $line = fgets($this->socket);
        print $line.'<br>';
        $this->reply = substr($line, 0, strlen($line) - 2);

        $words = explode(' ', $this->reply);

        $result = isset($this->replies[$words[0]]) ? $this->replies[$words[0]] : $words;

        if (is_null($result)) {
            throw new \Exception($this->reply);
        }

        if ($result[0] == 'VALUE') {
            $value = fread($this->socket, $result[3] + 2);

            return $value;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

First get query response of 'get1' key is VALUE get1 0 13 
Second get query reponse of 'get2' key is END

If i do it twice, the third response will return the value, the fourth one will return again END.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like according to the [memcached protocol](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L62), a retrieval request command is not finished until `END` is received but I don't see that your code accounts for this.

I think for your code you need to keep calling `fgets()` on a `get` or `gets` command until `END` is received, then parse the result.